# fixed-data-table-2 hover row background color

Tags: css, reactjs, fixed-data-table

I've been trying to get this to work for a while now and I haven't been able to come up with anything. The fixed-data-table-2 has a built in functionality for the row css, but that ends up being covered over by the individual cell css and wrapper. I've been doing research on this and I haven't been able to come up with a solution. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's my current code, please let me know what would need to be changed!

```
import s from './styles.css';

const FilteredCell = function({ data, rowIndex, columnKey, ...props }) {
  let output = data[rowIndex][columnKey];
  return <Cell {...props}>{output}</Cell>;
};

const rowClassName = () => s.row;
return(
          <Table
            height={filteredData.length * 30 + 60}
            rowsCount={filteredData.length}
            rowHeight={30}
            width={800}
            headerHeight={50}
            onRowClick={this.rowClicked}
            rowClassNameGetter={rowClassName}
          >
            <Column
              columnKey="chromosome"
              width={100}
              header={<Cell>Chromosome</Cell>}
              cell={<FilteredCell data={filteredData} />}
            />
            <Column
              columnKey="position"
              width={200}
              header={<Cell>Position</Cell>}
              cell={<FilteredCell data={filteredData} />}
            />
            <Column
              columnKey="rsid"
              width={150}
              header={<Cell>RSID</Cell>}
              cell={<FilteredCell data={filteredData} />}
            />
            <Column
              columnKey="gene"
              width={100}
              header={<Cell>Gene</Cell>}
              cell={<FilteredCell data={filteredData} />}
            />
            <Column
              columnKey="ref_allele"
              width={100}
              header={<Cell>Reference Allele</Cell>}
              cell={<FilteredCell data={filteredData} />}
            />
            <Column
              columnKey="alt_allele"
              width={100}
              header={<Cell>Alternative Allele</Cell>}
              cell={<FilteredCell data={filteredData} />}
            />
          </Table>
)
```

And Below is my current css

```
.row:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: yellow:
}
```

I have been trying to use some of the suggestions I found like

```
.public_fixedDataTable_bodyRow:hover .public_fixedDataTableCell_main
```

but it doesn't seem to be working or do anything. I'm not sure if how exactly to load it in right now. The way I'm exporting my component is with

```
export default connect(select)(withStyles(s)(ExpectoSnpTable));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just making complexing things in your code, no need to `s` when importing the `CSS` file.

This way you will have an access to all your classes

```
import './styles.css';
```

Now you can apply `.row` class using `className` attribute

```
 <Table
            height={filteredData.length * 30 + 60}
            rowsCount={filteredData.length}
            rowHeight={30}
            width={800}
            headerHeight={50}
            onRowClick={this.rowClicked}
            rowClassNameGetter={'row'}
            className={'row'} 
          >
```

Delete this

```
const rowClassName = () => s.row;
```

> No need to use `withStyle`

Comment: If I don't use the const rowClassName getter though, rowClassNameGetter asks for a function instead, I tried what you recommended, but now instead no styles from the stylesheet are loaded in.

Comment: Well, I don't know what is this attribute for rowClassNameGetter try to not using it if it possible.

Comment: Decided to just end up changing the background of each cell when each row is hovered using in line css, thanks for the help anyways!

Comment: I realize this is a few years old but I recently ran into a similar problem; the only change you need to pass in a function is `rowClassNameGetter={() => 'row'}`

Answer (score 2):

**This suggestion you found:**

```
.public_fixedDataTable_bodyRow:hover .public_fixedDataTableCell_main
```

easily worked for me without using the `rowClassNameGetter` and by just importing a **modified version** of the css module that you need to import as advised in the repo ([Fixed Data Table - Github Schrodinger](https://github.com/schrodinger/fixed-data-table-2))

"Add the default style-sheet `dist/fixed-data-table.css` using a link tag or import it with a CSS module."

**In my case, instead of just doing:**

```
import 'fixed-data-table-2/dist/fixed-data-table.css'
```

I copied it in my own style file, say, `fixed-data-table-2-modified.scss` and added:

```
.public_fixedDataTable_bodyRow:hover .public_fixedDataTableCell_main {
  background-color: #fff2d9; transition: all ease 0.5s;
}
```

**Then imported it as:**

```
import 'fixed-data-table-2-modified.scss'
```